# Large file download causing Chrome and Firefox to crash

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, download, crash, iso-image

I've been trying to download a file of 1.2GB(and my C: drive has over 400 free GB), and the same thing happens on both Chrome and Firefox(Haven't tried IE), on two different wifi networks I've tried connecting to.
The file shows up in downloads list in the browser, as it's doing what I presume to be assessing the size of the file, as the size listed next to the file is increasing, but when the listed size gets to around 684MB, the browser crashes, and the download ceases before it actually begins downloading.
Has anyone else had a similar problem? Any ideas as to how I can fix it?
BTW, the file is a .rar file containing an ISO.

Comment: If you are using Chrome then you can open your downloads folder and view the fragmented download as it is happening so you should see that you are actually getting about 684 MB onto your HDD. The fact that the size is increasing incrementally tells me that the server is configured improperly because normally a server will report the full size of the file before it sends it to you so your download bar knows how much is remaining. So ether the server is sending corrupt data around 684 MB or web browsers simply have trouble downloading unknown file sizes.

Comment: Is it ANY large file, or just that specific one? Is it available for download from any other source, or by another protocol (FTP?)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It never actually started downloading. If you use chrome then maybe you know how there's the the bar that fills with green as a file downloads. What happens is there is a sector of that bar that is green that rotates around, but the same amount is green at all times. It never actually begins the download, and there's no file in my downloads folder at all from it.

Comment: @user2649681 I see, have you tried downloading another large file through the browser? Does this website provide any other large, or small, files which you can try? I know the [Dungeon Siege 2 demo](http://www.fileplanet.com/155749/download/Dungeon-Siege-2-Demo-%5BSingle-player%5D-v2.2) is 911 MB, does this download act the same as the 1.2 GB rar file?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Yeah, I'm trying it now, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: Cool, let me know what happens. If that works then hopefully you don't have some weird 1.2 GB file issue going on. Here is a [1.5 GB zip file - 3DMark Windows v1.4.828 Installer](http://www.gamershell.com/download_111293.shtml)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus, yeah, the download failed.

Comment: Are you using Windows? I would try checking your [Event Viewer](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/open-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7) application logs and you should see an entry for FireFox/Chrome. You can try Googling the error codes.

Comment: Did the Dungeon Siege 2 demo behave similarly to the rar file or did something actually start downloading?

Comment: It got cancelled.

Comment: Have you checked out your event viewer?

Comment: What do I look for?

Comment: I got a different file that went to about 800MB, but then crashed my browser again?

Answer (score 0):

You might try Free Download Manager (FDM), http://www.freedownloadmanager.org/, which shows details of the download process. FDM can be installed stand-alone or set to intercept downloads made in IE, Firefox or other browser.
BTW, there are applications with the same name which contain malware -- be sure to get it from the correct site, and, if you wish, send the executable to Virus Total, https://www.virustotal.com/, to confirm its safety.